# running jar file with multiple arguments in perl

Tags: perl

Im trying to run a jar file. this jar file will output multiple question in console manner, i want to eliminate the console and i need to input a value in order to proceed.

e.g :

A. Choose value 1 :

[1] Windows

[2] Unix

Input : 2

B. Choose value 2 :

[1] Oracle

[2] DB2

Input : 1

Im trying :

`"java -jar program.jar < abc.txt"` where 
abc.txt has a value of :

2

1

3

etc.

but its not working its only getting the first value.
please help. thanks.

btw, ive also try  :

`OPEN PIPE, "| java -jar program.jar";

 open (FH, /abc.txt)

 print PIPE "$res";

 close FH;

close PIPE;`

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Note sure why your current approach is not working. You may want to take a look at the [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) module on CPAN.

Comment: Thanks guys! will try that. btw, any scripts to see how to use expect? Regards.

Comment: The page I linked to contains the documentation for the module. At the end, there are some code examples. The one on how to automate login seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the entire contents of the file is being piped all at once to the first prompt, so the remainder of the file just gets 'swallowed' and lost

So, +1 to jackrabbit's suggestion of using the Expect module instead

Comment: Thanks guys! will try that. btw, any scripts to seehow touse expect? Regards.